# Using fs.stat to get stats from a file inside a docker container directory

Tags: node.js, docker, boot2docker, fs

I've got a test which uses fs.stat (NodeJS) to check the size of a file inside the Downloads directory. This works fine locally.

When I run the same test in jenkins, which runs the tests inside a docker container, it fails to locate the directory/file. Getting this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Downloads/test.txt'
```

'Downloads/test.txt' is the path I've set in my test. I've verified this file exists inside the docker container Downloads folder.

Comment: Path shown in error message is /Downloads/test.txt, do you have Download directory in root of your file system?

Comment: inside the docker container, the download folder is in the root directory, so yes.

Comment: I'm thinking it is something to do with the fs module as i have another test which is able to read the Downloads folder that does not use fs.